# c# to javascript for YUI calendar

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, yui

I am looking to run a select statement in my C# code behind pages to select dates from a MSSQL table so that I can highlight booked dates in my YUI calendar. I have done this manually by using the following JavaScript (this highlights September 1st):

```
YAHOO.example.calendar.cal1.addRenderer("9/1/2012",YAHOO.example.calendar.cal1.renderCellStyleHighlight1);
```

Is there a way to get the dates that I have selected from the database to then be 'echoed' into JavaScript like below? I know how to do this in PHP but not in ASP.NET!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to return the date, here is a quick tutorial: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/10/04/asp-net-ajax-pagemethods.aspx